# makewhatis and logrotate cron job schedule

Tags: linux, centos, cron

In `/etc/cron.daily/`,

- logrotate*
- makewhatis.cron*

I understand that above are daily cron jobs. How to display the time set for logrotate and makewhatis.cron?

Its not listed when I tried this script:

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Comment: What operating system and distribution are you using?

Comment: Im using CentOS Linux

Comment: Which version of CentOS Linux?

Comment: Using CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `/etc/anacrontab`

Cron runs anacron, which runs then cron.daily/weekly/monthly...

If you have the default files, you'll see something like:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Basically, this means that the jobs in `/etc/cron.daily/` will run sequentially beginning at 3:05am + a random delay of up-to-45 minutes.

For example, you can see when makewhatis ran in the past by searching your logs:

```
# grep makewhatis /var/log/cron

/var/log/cron:Jan 25 03:35:20 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[21432]: starting makewhatis.cron
/var/log/cron:Jan 25 03:35:21 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[21776]: finished makewhatis.cron
/var/log/cron:Jan 26 03:39:21 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[54618]: starting makewhatis.cron
/var/log/cron:Jan 26 03:39:33 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[58997]: finished makewhatis.cron
/var/log/cron:Jan 27 03:40:15 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[56366]: starting makewhatis.cron
/var/log/cron:Jan 27 03:40:16 xt run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[56710]: finished makewhatis.cron
```